# Кеширование ресурсов с CDN при помощи sw-precache

Tags: javascript, gulp, service-worker

Пытаюсь сгенерировать сервис-воркер при помощи sw-precache, который должен кешировать внешние ресурсы. С кешированием ресурсов, которые лежат рядом проблем нет, делается это таким образом:

```js
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', ['copy-sw-scripts'], () => {
  const rootDir = 'dist';
  const filepath = path.join(rootDir, 'service-worker.js');

  return swPrecache.write(filepath, {
    cacheId: pkg.name || 'app',
    staticFileGlobs: [
      `${rootDir}/images/**/*`,
      `${rootDir}/fonts/**/*.woff2`,
      `${rootDir}/scripts/**/*.js`,
      `${rootDir}/styles/**/*.css`,
      `${rootDir}/*.{html,json}`
    ],
    stripPrefix: rootDir + '/'
  });
});
```

Генерировать сервис-воркер, который будет кешировать внешние ресурсы пытаюсь вот так:

```js
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', ['copy-sw-scripts'], () => {
  const rootDir = 'dist';
  const filepath = path.join(rootDir, 'service-worker.js');

  return swPrecache.write(filepath, {
    cacheId: pkg.name || 'app',
    importScripts: [
      'scripts/sw/sw-toolbox.js',
      'scripts/sw/runtime-caching.js'
    ],
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https:\/\/cdn\.mysite\.ua\/assets/,
        handler: 'networkFirst'
      }
    ],
    stripPrefix: rootDir + '/'
  });
});
```

Но нужного результата это не приносит. Как это сделать правильно?

Использую sw-precache, sw-toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось достаточно просто, вместе с динамическим кэшированием файлов с CDN, надо было еще и кэшировать «локальные» файлы, так всё работает:

```js
gulp.task('generate-service-worker', ['copy-sw-scripts'], () => {
  const rootDir = 'dist';
  const filepath = path.join(rootDir, 'service-worker.js');

  return swPrecache.write(filepath, {
    cacheId: pkg.name || 'app',
    importScripts: [
      'scripts/sw/sw-toolbox.js',
      'scripts/sw/runtime-caching.js'
    ],
    staticFileGlobs: [
      `${rootDir}/*.{html,json}`
    ],
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https:\/\/cdn\.mysite\.ua\/assets/,
        handler: 'networkFirst'
      }
    ],
    stripPrefix: rootDir + '/'
  });
});
```